# HMS Cloud debugging emulator opens constantly Huawei app without an action

Tags: java, android-studio, emulation, huawei-mobile-services

[image][image]I download HMS plugin and whenever I open cloud debugging and run my app, Emulator opens Huawei app. So how can I prevent this? thanks

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot this issue happened? If it was application prompts to update the HMS Core, you could update the HMS Core as prompted or ignore it.

Comment: I add screenshot. Issue happened when cloud debugging opened

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get rid of the splash ads from the remote test device by simply clicking the Home button as shown in the screenshot below. If the ads may come back, you click the Home button again.

[image]

You can select another cloud debugging device like Mate 30 Pro or P40 Pro. They don't display the splash ads.

[image]